# No response returned and app gets down when requesting a sign in for Account Linking

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Instantiating a `SignIn` using `conv.ask()` always fails. My action says no-response when sign-in flow is called and it leaves my app.

In my `Firebase Functions log`, the json below was spitted, which probably means that it is correctly called, but there is something wrong. I tried updating my `Actions on Google` console, cleared sign in setting in the Directory page, tested in some different accounts, cleared data to reset in my action app and as such. Needless to say, I set `clientId` inside the `dialogflow` class paramerter.

I totally have no idea for this. I have done many projects for `Google Assistant` apps which required `SignIn` `Account Linking` flow. But I encounter this strange behavior only for this project. What should I do? SDK verions is `"actions-on-google": "^2.6.0"`.

```
Response {
  "status": 200,
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  },
  "body": {
    "payload": {
      "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "systemIntent": {
          "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
          "data": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValueSpec",
            "optContext": "For account creation"
          }
        },
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "Please do sign in "
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
Inside conv.user　

{
"raw":{
"locale":"ja-JP",
"userId":"ABwppHGDYgpYn2waeaDyKoMZIqhg4ZxO56vXeAhs-43ZUC6VF3SdCvUGY3L1Vd08eTY_hRLfjrvp4"
},
"storage":{
},
"_id":"ABwppHGDYgpYn2waeaDyKoMZIqhg4ZxO56vXeAhs-43ZUC6VF3SdCvUGY3L1Vd08eTY_hRSfjrvp4",
"locale":"ja-JP",
"permissions":{
},
"last":{
},
"name":{
},
"entitlements":{
},
"access":{
},
"profile":{

}
}
```

```
// THIS SEEMS TO BE CALLED according to Firebase Functions Log
app.intent('StartSignIn', (conv) => {
    conv.ask(new SignIn('For account creation'));
})


app.intent(INTENT.SignInIntent, (conv, params, signin) => {
    console.log('INTENT.SignInIntent is called');
    if (signin.status !== 'OK') {
        conv.close(`failed`);
        return;
    }
    conv.close('please wait');
});
```

**UPDATE**
I figured out the solution by making another folder and doing `firebase init`, and connected it to a new `Firebase` project. The main reason is unknown but it worked well by creating a new project.

Comment: Without seeing a list of your Dialogflow intents and your complete fulfillment, it's difficult to reproduce this issue. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem?

Comment: @MaxWiederholt I fixed the issue by creating a new project.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your new project!